# Prevent Catastrophic Backtracking in Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, backtracking

I have a code to scrape a million websites and detect contact info from their homepage.

For some reasons, when I run code, it gets stuck and does not proceed after crawling about 60k requests, I am marking the website URLs in my DB as `status=done`

I have run code several times but it gets stuck around 60k requests.

It doesnt get stuck on a certain website.

Here is Regex I am using

```
    emails = re.findall('[\w\.-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w\.-]+', lc_body)
    mobiles = re.findall(r"(\(?(?<!\d)\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4})(?!\d)|(?<!\d)(\+\d{11})(?!\d)", lc_body)
    abns = re.findall('[a][-\.\s]??[b][-\.\s]??[n][-\:\.\s]?[\:\.\s]?(\d+[\s\-\.]?\d+[\s\-\.]?\d+[\s\-\.]?\d+)', lc_body)

    licences = re.findall(r"(Licence|Lic|License|Licence)\s*(\w*)(\s*|\s*#\s*|\s*.\s*|\s*-\s*|\s*:\s+)(\d+)", lc_body, re.IGNORECASE)
```

My thought is `licences`'s regex is causing issues, how can I simplify it? How can I remove Backtracking ?

I want to find all Licence numbers possible.

It can be  `License No: 2543` , `License: 2543`, `License # 2543`,  `License #2543`,  `License# 2543` and many other combinations as well.

Comment: The best practice is to use alternatives in an alternation group that do not match at the same location. Please provide a string that causes issues.

Comment: `(Licence|Lic|License|Licence)` => `(Licence|Lic|License)` for starters :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: No, `Lic(?:en[cs]e)?`. The issue is caused with the third group though, `(\s*|\s*#\s*|\s*.\s*|\s*-\s*|\s*:\s+)` - all alternatives start with `\s*`. What is it supposed to match?

Comment: also: wouldn't it be better to compile the regexes and use the compiled version? Would certainly save some time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to extract Licence numbers ... `License No: 2543` , `License: 2543`, `License # 2543`,  `License #2543`,  `License# 2543` and there can be many other combinations as well ...

Comment: Aha, so the `.` is a literal one? It must be escaped then. See [`Lic(?:en[cs]e)?(?:\s+\w+:?)?(?:\s*[#.:-])?\s*\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/rhKePl/1)

Comment: Or better - `Lic(?:en[cs]e)?(?:\W*No:)?\W*\d+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please post a detailed answer on that? And any other suggestions you have in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused with the third group: `(\s*|\s*#\s*|\s*.\s*|\s*-\s*|\s*:\s+)` - all alternatives start with `\s*` here. This causes lots of redundant backtracking as these alternatives can match at the same location in a string. *The best practice is to use alternatives in an alternation group that do not match at the same location.*

Now, looking at the strings you need to match, I suggest using

```
Lic(?:en[cs]e)?(?:\W*No:)?\W*\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ8rxt/1)

Make the pattern more specific and linear, get rid of as many [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) as possible, use [optional non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500422/are-optional-non-capturing-groups-redundant) and character classes.

**Details**:

- `Lic(?:en[cs]e)?` - `Lic` followed with 1 or 0 occurrences (the `(?:...)?` is an optional [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) since `?` quantifier matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpatterns) of `ence` or `ense`  (the character class `[sc]` matches either `s` or `c` and is much more efficient than `(s|c)`)
- `(?:\W*No:)?` - a non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of 0+ non-word chars (with `\W*`) followed with `No:` substring
- `\W*`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.