# Regex to get everything before the first slash except between quotes

Tags: regex

I am looking to create a Regex to extract everything before the first slash except if it is in single or double quotes. Currently, I have:

```
^(.*?)/
```

Now, I am at a lost. Based on the different texts below, I just want the bolded part below:

**Text**

**abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno** /123
/abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno 123
**abc,**/def,"/ghi",jkl,mno /123
**abc,def,"/ghi",jkl,mno** /123
**abc,def,'/ghi',jkl,mno** /123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[^/"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l7ZSMM/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^/"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `[^/"']` - any char other than `/`, `"` and `'`
  - `|` - or
  - `"[^"]*"` -  a `"`, any 0+ chars other than `"`, and then `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `'[^']*'` -  a `'`, any 0+ chars other than `'`, and then `'`

Comment: So beautiful! ;)

Comment: Why use a non-capturing group? Is there a benefit?

Comment: @Nick See [Are non-capturing groups redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500422/are-non-capturing-groups-redundant/31500517#31500517)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(.*?)\/(?=([^\"\']*\"[^\"\']*\")*[^\"\']*$)
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpbvQo/2)

Using Group 1