# groovy regular expression difficulty

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a string like this: 1R12 or 2EURO16.

- First character is 1 or 2 (numeric)
- Middle is a letter or a word (R,L,X,Y,B or EURO)
- End is 10,12,14,16 (numeric)

What I tried is this:

```
(^1|2)(R|L|X|Y|B|EURO)(10|12|14|16$)
```

But this gives negative result.
What would be a correct or possible regex?

Answer (score 4):

The `(^1|2)` matches `1` at the start of the string and `2` anywhere in a string. Similarly, `(10|12|14|16$)` matches `10`, `12` and `14` anywhere inside a string and `16` at the end of the string.

You need to rearrange the anchors:

```
/^[12](?:[RLXYB]|EURO)(?:10|12|14|16)$/
```

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B12%5D(%3F%3A%5BRLXYB%5D%7CEURO)(%3F%3A10%7C12%7C14%7C16)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[12]` - `1` or `2`
- `(?:[RLXYB]|EURO)` - `R`, `L`, `X`, `Y`, `B` or `EURO`
- `(?:10|12|14|16)` - `10`, `12`, `14` or `16`
- `$` - end of string

**NOTE**: If you use `==~` operator in Groovy, you do not need anchors at all because `==~` requires a full string match:

```
println("1EURO16" ==~ /[12](?:[RLXYB]|EURO)(?:10|12|14|16)/) // => true
println("1EURO19" ==~ /[12](?:[RLXYB]|EURO)(?:10|12|14|16)/) // => false
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/B9WJMY).

Comment: Hi, this is purely inquisitive but may I ask why you chose to use non-capturing groups? According to regex101 it takes the same number of steps to perform the regex with or without those. Is it some sort of memory optimization?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus See [Are non-capturing groups redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500517/3832970). Actually, the rule of thumb is to use non-capturing groups when the texts they capture are not going to be retrieved, or used for in-pattern backreferencing. Just best practice.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will try to regex more responsibly moving forward :-)