# Improve code with checking element in array is digit

Tags: arrays, regex, scala

I want to check that each element in String is digit. Firstly, I split the String to an Array by a regexp `[, ]+` expression and then I try to check each element by forall and isDigit.

```
object Test extends App {
  val st = "1, 434, 634, 8"

  st.split("[ ,]+") match {
    case arr if !arr.forall(_.forall(_.isDigit)) => println("not an array")
    case arr if arr.isEmpty                      => println("bad delimiter")
    case _                                       => println("success")
  }
}
```

How can I improve this code and `!arr.forall(_.forall(_.isDigit))`?

Comment: The array returned by `split` will never be empty.

Comment: what answer should be if you pass string `1 2 3, 123`? And what do you mean by `improve this code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matches` that requires the string to fully match the pattern:

```
st.matches("""\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*""")
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/IQH73152) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3SWrzI/1).

**Details**

- In a triple quoted string literal, there is no need to double escape backslashes that are part of regex escapes
- Anchors - `^` and `$` - are implicit when the pattern is used with `.matches`
- The regex means *1+ digits followed with 0 or more repetitions of a comma enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces and then 1+ digits*.

Comment: Returns **false** for strings like `" 1,2,4"` and `"1,2,4 "`. Not sure if that's desired results or not.

Comment: @jwvh It is expected, see the sample input in the question that has no leading/trailing whitespace. Anyway, it can easily be added with `\s*` at the start and end of the pattern

Comment: Just curious: Why make it non-capture? What advantage does the `?:` add?

Comment: @jwvh See [Are non-capturing groups redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500422/are-non-capturing-groups-redundant). In short: the best practice is to only use capturing groups only when you need to access part of the regex match after it occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be simplified while also making it a bit more robust.

```
val st = "1,434 , 634   , 8"  //a little messier but still valid

st.split(",").forall(" *\\d+ *".r.matches)  //res0: Boolean = true
```

I'm assuming strings like `"1,,,434 , 634  2 , "` should fail.

The regex can be put in a variable so that it is compiled only once.

```
val digits = " *\\d+ *".r
st.split(",").forall(digits.matches)
```

Comment: nice approach @jwvh