# Regex named caption groups separation for optional part

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to have a regex with two named caption groups that will catch strings like this :

```
djhkaisd#@893ian 493089403
jsd%2ckgm* 283482374
ajfioasjf26fa
omioriew
```

and so, no new lines or white spaces inside the first word but the first part ( name ) can contain any other char ( any char that . represents ),
the second part is always a simple number, but it not a must ( with the space before it )

The one i got is :

```
^(?<name>.+)( (?<number>[0-9]+)){0,1}
```

or

```
^(?<name>.+)( (?<number>[0-9]+))?
```

The problem is that the `number` caption group is always empty and the whole string is going inside the `name` caption group, for example :

name = `asfajsfasd 329042390`

number =

i want to have like this :

name = `asfajsfasd`

number = `329042390`

Any ideas how it can be done ?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/hq87wS/1

Comment: Use `\S+` for no newlines or whitespaces for the first word `^(?<name>\S+)(?: (?<number>[0-9]+))?$` https://regex101.com/r/xuk7hu/1

Comment: Thanks both, it works
@Thefourthbird why the ?: is also needed ?

Comment: If you want to capture the number only without the space, you can include it in the match, but outside of the pattern for the number. Then you have 2 capturing groups. If you make it a capturing group, you will have 3 groups. https://regex101.com/r/OVoVok/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, i understand thanks ive learened something new today :)
I dont really care that i have one or more extra groups that i dont really need but its nice to know that i can annotate the this is not a caption group.
Should i care about this extra group ? or its just cosmetic ?

Comment: See more about `(?:...)` in [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471). To understand their importance, also see [Are non-capturing groups redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500422/are-non-capturing-groups-redundant)