# capture german date formats using regex

Tags: python, regex, date, validation

I dont (need to) care about performance!

My regex matches the date format `dd.mm.yyyy`

```
((([0][1-9]|[12][\d])|[3][01])[./]([0][13578]|[1][02])[./][1-9]\d\d\d)|((([0][1-9]|[12][\d])|[3][0])[./]([0][13456789]|[1][012])[./][1-9]\d\d\d)|(([0][1-9]|[12][\d])[-/][0][2][./][1-9]\d([02468][048]|[13579][26]))|(([0][1-9]|[12][0-8])[./][0][2][./][1-9]\d\d\d)
```

Here are the dates my regex does not match yet. **Any help appreciated.**

```
09. Juni 1997
01.Aug.1995
27.06. 1997
29.02.1996
21. 01. 1999
28.05. 1996
07..4..1995
20:03:1998
9.4.1997
14 .03 - 1995
```

I started out by trying to add the month letters but failed (probably because of the whitespaces between them)

here is a regex that validates the months' letter order (Januar, Februar, März, April, Mai, Juni, August, September, Oktober, November, Dezember)

```
(?:J(anuar|u(n|li))|Februar|Mä(rz|i)|A(pril|ugust)|(((Sept|Nov|Dez)em)|Okto)ber)
```

I found this on the internet, which focusses on the issue if only 3 letters of the months are availiable

```
(((([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30))\-([A,a][P,p][R,r]|[J,j][U,u][N,n]|[S,s][E,e][P,p]|[N,n][O,o][V,v]))|((([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-([J,j][A,a][N,n]|[M,m][A,a][R,r]|[M,m][A,a][Y,y]|[J,j][U,u][L,l]|[A,a][U,u][G,g]|[O,o][C,c][T,t]|[D,d][E,e][C,c])))\-[0-9]{4}$)|(^(([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-8]))\-([F,f][E,e][B,b])\-[0-9]{2}(([02468][1235679])|([13579][01345789]))$)|(^(([1-9])|([0][1-9])|([1][0-9])|([2][0-9]))\-([F,f][E,e][B,b])\-[0-9]{2}(([02468][048])|([13579][26]))
```

Comment: You could try the [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
pattern = r"""(?x)(?<!d)(?:
  (?:(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d)|3[01])\s?[./:-][\s.]?(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|J(?:an(?:uar)?|uli?)|M(?:ärz?|ai)|Aug(?:ust)?|Dez(?:ember)?|Okt(?:ober)?)\s?(?:[./:-][\s.]?)?[1-9]\d\d\d|
  (?:(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d)|30)\s?[./:-][\s.]?(?:0?[13-9]|1[012]|J(?:an(?:uar)?|u[nl]i?)|M(?:ärz?|ai)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:tember)?|(?:Nov|Dez)(?:ember)?|Okt(?:ober)?)\s?(?:[./:-][\s.]?)?[1-9]\d\d\d|
  (?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d)\s?[./:-][\s.]?(?:0?2|Fe(?:b(?:ruar)?)?)\s?(?:[./:-][\s.]?)?[1-9]\d(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])|
  (?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-8])\s?[./:-][\s.]?(?:0?2|Fe(?:b(?:ruar)?)?)\s?(?:[./:-][\s.]?)?[1-9]\d\d\d
)(?!\d)"""
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFmCdQ/2).

Main POIs:

- The month regex is `(?:J(?:an(?:uar)?|u[nl]i?)|Fe(?:b(?:ruar)?)?|M(?:ärz?|ai)|A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Sep(?:tember)?|(?:Nov|Dez)(?:ember)?|Okt(?:ober)?)` and it is tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/tClRRs/2/). Adjust for shortenings as you see fit.
- `Febraury` pattern is used separately for the last two alternations (they are specifically for Februrary) and is subtracted from the month pattern for the rest of the alternatives
- From the first alternation, for 31-day months, February, April, June, September and November months are removed
- Leading zeros in days and months is made optional by adding `?` quantifier after `0`
- The separator between days and months is changed to `\s?[./:-][\s.]?`: an optional whitespace, a char from `./:-` char set, and then an optional whitespace or `.`
- The separator between months and years is changed to `\s?(?:[./:-][\s.]?)?`: an optional whitespace and then an optional sequence of a char from `./:-` char set and then an optional whitespace or `.`.

The numeric boundaries, `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)`, are added on both ends to make sure there are no other digits on both ends of the match.

Comment: It looks like you made every single group a non-capturing one -- why? Wouldn't it work just as well with regular groups? The `?:` seem to do nothing except adding additional clutter to this already extremely complex regex. (Very impressive nonetheless!)

Comment: @fsimonjetz See [Are non-capturing groups redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500422/are-non-capturing-groups-redundant) Caprturing groups need extra memory allocation for the substrings captured, and that slows it all down.